# Possible to check if a pointer is freed/invalid?

Tags: c, memory-management

I think the short answer to this is "no", but suppose I have the following function:

```
void print_table(const hash_table *table)
{

    printf("-------------------------- SIZE: %zu / %zu -----------------------\n", table->count, table->size);
    for (int i=0; i < table->size; i++) {
        hash_item *item = table->items[i];
        if (item != NULL && item != &HT_DELETED_ITEM)
            printf("Idx: %d {%s: %s}\n", i, item->key, item->value);

    }
}
```

Of course this will `seg fault` if the `table` has been free'd. I thought 'catching' that would be as simple as doing a null check at the top:

```
// this top part see
if (table == NULL) {
    printf("[Empty]");
    return;
}
```

But of course nothing is that simple in C. Is there a way to do a check like that in C, or maybe even a hack-ish way to store perhaps something like a boolean in a struct saying whether it's been 'freed' or not?

As an example of what I get now:

```
// first time running in with a valid `table` object
-------------------------- SIZE: 2 / 64 -----------------------
Idx: 10 {Mark: Jones}
Idx: 40 {Ben: Johnson}

// second time after free'd
Segmentation fault: 11 <-- I know this, but any way to short-circuit this?
```

Comment: use c++ and unique_ptr<> ?

Comment: @OznOg I don't know c++

Comment: I'd say, just make sure your pointer is `NULL` whenever it is not being used. When you initialize it, unless you assign it an address immediately, make it point to `NULL`. After freeing, immediately make it point to `NULL`. Whenever you need to check if it's pointing to something then, you can see whether it's pointing to `NULL` or not.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 I see,  does that mean in the 'delete' function I'd need to pass a pointer to the pointer-struct instead of just the pointer-struct itself?

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 that is, the delete function would be something like `void hash_table_delete(hash_table** table_ptr)` ?

Comment: @carl.hiass Yes, I think that would be a good idea so that you can modify the pointer to point to `NULL` afterwards. An example would be `void hash_table_delete(hash_table** table_ptr) {free(*hash_table_ptr); *hash_table_ptr = NULL;}` According to the [man page on `free`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free), `free` will not do anything if the pointer is `NULL`: _"If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed. "_ Therefore, you don't have to even do any checking for `NULL`, `free` will do it for you. Of course if `*has_table_ptr` is an invalid address, there will be UB but thats the caller's fault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be handled by documented pre-conditions. If you write a function, it should document what the required pre-conditions are to call the function and then it's the responsibility of the calling code to ensure the pre-conditions are met. This should be a pre-condition.

For example, it is a pre-condition of calling `free` that the pointer passed in either point to memory allocated by `malloc` (or a related function) and not freed yet. The `free` function does not attempt to check if this pre-condition is met because it's the responsibility of the calling code to do that.

Do not rely on a pointer value being `NULL`. That's not a good habit to get into and it will serve you badly as you continue learning more complex programming skills. While it can certainly make sense to use a pointer value of `NULL` to indicate that an object hasn't been allocated or has been freed, it should *never* be used without thought and *only* used where it specifically makes sense to do that.

The main reason is simple -- there will be times when there will be two pointers to the same object. You often can't set *both* to `NULL` when you call `free`. If you get in the habit of assuming that a pointer will always be `NULL` if it's not pointing to something allocated, you will struggle with code like that.